# CakePHP: Using timthumb with Html helper?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I just started using cakephp for the first time and I don't know how to use timthumb with the html helpers. My code goes like this:

```
$this->Html->image('timthumb.php?src='.$receta['Receta']['imagen'].'&amp;h=246&amp;w=618', array(
        "alt" => $receta['Receta']['nombre_receta'],
        'url' => array('controller' => 'recetas', 'action' => 'view', 6)
    ));
```

and it gives me this html:

```
<a href="/recetas/view/6" ><img alt="Helado de Fresa" src="/img/timthumb.php?src=fresa.png&amp;h=246&amp;w=618"></a>
```

But that won't make the images show up. I have timthumb.php inside /webroot and the images inside /webroot/img . Also I have my cache and temp folders inside /webroot but I don't have a clue if that's ok?

If I remove the timthumb code the image will show (just not at the proper size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify that `timthumb.php` is in the web root, otherwise the `image` method assumes the timthumb script is in the `/img` folder. This also means you have to modify the value for the `src` parameter:

```
$this->Html->image('/timthumb.php?src=/img/'...
```

For the cache and tempory files I would use CakePHP's `/app/tmp` resp. `/app/tmp/cache` folders.

Comment: I moved timthumb.php to the webroot/img and that way it works. Otherwise cake will always add img before my url using image helper. Don't know if I should do it diferently though

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but you can also use [TimthumbPlugin](https://github.com/vishal-logiciel/TimthumbPlugin) for CakePHP. It wraps the timthumb library and provides an easy to use helper for that.